# Distinct Count expression ssas

Tags: count, ssas, distinct

I want to create a new calculated member in OLAP Cube to count the number of distinct clients,  I'm trying to write  this expression, but i don't know how to make it in MDX:

```
Distinct count ([DIM.Clients].[CuNumber], where Sum([Measures].[QQT - FACT Ventes] >=1)
```

Any help please !

Thanks!

---

Hi thank you for replies,

I spent couple of days trying to make the query work, but without big progress. 
First, I ran an SQL query on my datawarehouse to know what result should I get on my OLAP Cube, 
this is my SQL query:

```
use [Warehouse]

select count(*) as count_row

From 
(Select  F.FaCunumberX
from [dbo].[Dim_FaClients] F
inner join [dbo].[FACT_Ventes] V on F.[SK_FAClients] = V.SK_FaClients
inner join [dbo].[Dim_Date] D on D.SK_Date = V.SK_Date
where
D.Year = '2014'
Group by F.FaCunumberX
having  SUM(V.QQT) >= 1) test
```

the result I got is : 26026

On my OLAP Cube I tried several queries, but I didn't get the same result

this is some of the expressions that I tried :

```
WITH SET MySet AS

(Filter({[DIM FA Clients].[FaCuNumberX].[FaCuNumberX]}*{([Dim Date].[Year].&[2014],[Measures].[QQT - Fact Ventes])},[Measures].[QQT - Fact Ventes]>1 or [Measures].[QQT - Fact Ventes]=1)

MEMBER MEASURES.SETDISTINCTCOUNT AS
DISTINCTCOUNT(MySet)
SELECT {MEASURES.SETDISTINCTCOUNT} ON 0
FROM [CubeAll]
```

the result I got with this one is : 31575

I tried also this expression :

```
DistinctCount(Filter([DIM.Clients].[CuNumber].[CuNumber].Members,
                     [Measures].[QQT - FACT Ventes] >= 1
                    )
             )
```

the same result : 31575

sincerely, I don't see what I'm missing on my expressions.

Thank's  for your help !

Comment: Does this cube only have the one dimension ([DIM])?

Comment: There are 5 dimensions, but in this case I use  Clients dimension only

Comment: See if the Distinct Count example here helps you:  http://docs.intersystems.com/ens20121/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=D2GMDX_ch_calculated_members

Answer (score 1):

This would be something like

```
DistinctCount(Filter([DIM.Clients].[CuNumber].[CuNumber].Members,
                     [Measures].[QQT - FACT Ventes] >= 1
                    )
             )
```

See the documentation of [Filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146037.aspx) and [DistinctCount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145519.aspx) for details.